# Array search and replace with Sublime Text's regular expression

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

How can I search for multiple words and replace each one by a specific word using regular expression? In PHP it would be :

```
$string = 'The quick bar foo jumps over the bazzy qux';
$patterns = array('foo', 'bar');
$replacements = array('baz', 'qux');
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
// Outputs: The quick qux baz jumps over the bazzy qux
```

I would like to do it inside of Sublime Text which uses Boost Syntax for seach and replace ([reference](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_overview.html)) which seems to be pearl syntax.

Comment: As you can see this is not part of the regex syntax, but a higher-level feature of the regex engine (that executes multiple independent regexes separately). If Sublime Text does not offer that functionality, then all you can do is executing multiple replacements in a row manually.

Comment: m.buettner is right: regex can't hold multiple conditional mappings like that. You'll have to create one regex for each target and replacement mapping you need.

Answer (score 1):

At least you can do this to replace an array of possible strings with a specific replacement:

Find:

```
foo|bar
```

Replace:

```
cow
```

This will replace all instances of `foo` and `bar` with `cow`.

I'm not sure how to fine-tune the replacements specific to `foo` or `bar`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the regex enabled search to find all of one word then hit find all. Then simply type your replacement word in. Repeat for each word you want to replace.